# Does the code coverage affects the lightning pages in target org?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, unit-test

I am using **codeCoverage()** method with ***1000 lines of i++;*** to test a package.

I did not actually wrote the required test class because this is just a test org.

I have *lighting pages* which are *not opening* at all, they are blank in target org where I've installed my package.

My *question* is: ***Does test classes effect any vf pages to lighting communication or is this (getting blank Lightning pages) completely different issue?***

Comment: the package that you install. Is it a managed package?

Comment: Yes. It is a managed package.

Comment: If it is a managed packaged, I believe you cannot see the code, b/c when you open you see blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code coverage only affects deployments, and has absolutely no effect on performance of any particular page or component. You'll need to use the Developer Console and your browser's Developer Tools (F12) to diagnose the problem(s) you're having.